# Insert image in resources folder Java

Tags: java, image, netbeans, filechooser

I have a database `WAMP` in which, despite other fields, I can insert the name followed by the extension of an image, for instance, `"imagen1.jpg"`.
The program I am doing is written in `Java` and `SQL` for the sentences and I'm using the IDE of Netbeans to do it.
I have a type called `"Imagenes.java"` in which I pick the route of an image to, in this way, insert it in my `Jpanel` or `Jlabel`.

```
public class Imagenes extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    String path;
    ImageIcon imag;

    public Imagenes(int width,int height,String path)
    {    
        this.path=path;
        this.setSize(width,height);        
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics graph)
    {
        Dimension tam = getSize();
        if (imag!=null)
        graph.drawImage(imag.getImage(),0,0,tam.width, tam.height, null); 
        else
        {
            ImageIcon imagenFondo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));        
            graph.drawImage(imagenFondo.getImage(),0,0,tam.width, tam.height, null);        
        }
        setOpaque(false);
        super.paintComponent(graph);
    }

}
```

All the images I've inserted are already saved in a folder called `"resources"`.
Therefore, I want to add to the `"resources"` folder, images from the computer I pick from a `"fileChooser"`.
I've tried it in a thousand ways, putting the complete route and there is no way for the folder to being recognized. However, it
copies the images in the source folder.
I've tried type of routes like `'\\resources\\imagen1.jpg'`, Java specific, but It doesn't pick it properly. But If I do
a print of the string of the route, this is correct.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try typing `"src/resources/imagen1.jpg"`

Comment: but which method should i use to copy a image from my computer to resources folder?

Comment: So all you want to do is just copy a file from one dir to another dir? Is that your only problem?

Comment: Yes, im not able to copy it to resources folder, only to source, when i compile and try it, it says that the path doesnt exists, but when i print it on the console, it seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `ImageIcon(path)` instead of `ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path))`. You may want to try `"src/resources/imagen1.jpg"`. Netbeans will search from the ProjectRoot. So just typing `"resources/imagen1.jpg"`, it wont be found. You need to add the `src`

```
ProjectRootDir
            src
               resources
                      imagen1.jpg
```

When you use`ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path));` The program will try and locate the Image from the `classes` dir in the `build` dir. If you place the resources dir in the `classes` dir, using `ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(path))` should work

```
ProjectRootDir
            build
                classes
                     resources
                             imagen1.jpg
```

In the above scenario, your `path` would be `"resources/imagen.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

How could I use this to save in resources folder?

```
    // declare JFileChooser
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

// let the user choose the destination file
if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    // indicates whether the user still wants to export the settings
    boolean doExport = true;

    // indicates whether to override an already existing file
    boolean overrideExistingFile = false;

    // get destination file
    File destinationFile = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

    // check if file already exists
    while (doExport && destinationFile.exists() && !overrideExistingFile) {
        // let the user decide whether to override the existing file
        overrideExistingFile = (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Replace file?", "Export Settings", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

        // let the user choose another file if the existing file shall not be overridden
        if (!overrideExistingFile) {
            if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                // get new destination file
                destinationFile = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                // seems like the user does not want to export the settings any longer
                doExport = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // perform the actual export
    if (doExport) {
        // the code to write the file goes here...
    }
```